# Sorting Hash of Hashes by value (and return the hash, not an array)

Tags: ruby, data-structures, hash, sorting

I have the following hash:

```
user = {
  'user' => {
    'title' => {'weight' => 1, .... }
    'body' => {'weight' => 4, ....}
     ....
     ....
  }
}
```

Is is possible to get the User sorted by the weight key of its child hashes?

I looked in the Hash.sort, but it looks like it returns array rather than my original hash sorted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9, `Hash`es are sorted, but `Hash#sort` still returns an `Array` of `Array`s. Imagine that! It does imply that you can build your own sorting method on top of it.

```
class Hash
  def sorted_hash(&block)
    self.class[sort(&block)]   # Hash[ [[key1, value1], [key2, value2]] ]
  end
end
```

`Hash`es are unsorted in Ruby 1.8. If you want Ruby 1.8 compatibility, you can use ActiveSupport's [`OrderedHash`](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cb534524389bb4f407fc268a0bb7a7cffb6785a9/activesupport/lib/active_support/ordered_hash.rb). It behaves like a 1.9-`Hash`, so you can define the same `sorted_hash` method on it:

```
class ActiveSupport::OrderedHash
  def sorted_hash(&block)
    self.class[sort(&block)]
  end
end

hash = ActiveSupport::OrderedHash.new
hash["b"] = "b"
hash["a"] = "a"
hash               #=> {"b"=>"b", "a"=>"a"}  => unsorted
hash.sorted_hash   #=> {"a"=>"a", "b"=>"b"}  => sorted!
```

You have to copy the `sorted_hash` method to your code, because it does not exist by default!

**Update for deep sorting:**
If you're looking to sort on something else than the hash key, pass a block to the `sorted_hash` method as follows (assuming the implementation from above):

```
hash = ActiveSupport::OrderedHash.new
hash["a"] = { "attr" => "2", "..." => "..." }
hash["b"] = { "attr" => "1", "..." => "..." }

# Unsorted.
hash 
  #=> {"a"=>{"attr"=>"2", "..."=>"..."}, "b"=>{"attr"=>"1", "..."=>"..."}}

# Sort on the "attr" key. (Assuming every value is a Hash itself!)
hash.sorted_hash { |a, b| a[1]["attr"] <=> b[1]["attr"] }
  #=> {"b"=>{"attr"=>"1", "..."=>"..."}, "a"=>{"attr"=>"2", "..."=>"..."}}
```

Comment: I did not get you. I looked in the OrderedHash source code of the rails 2.3.2 and I don't see anything in regards to sorting methods.

Comment: @satynos: I clarified it a bit, hopefully. You need to define sorted_hash yourself, but it's really easy! Just copy my implementation if you want.

Comment: @molf: excellent... thanks for the feedback and help on implementation. Also if I implement your method in Hash class, will it work? or should it have to be implemented in ActiveSupport::OrderedHash ?

Comment: @satynos: only use the Hash class if you are using Ruby 1.9. Ruby 1.8 Hashes are unordered by definition -- you will not be able to sort. Therefore, for Ruby 1.8+ compatibility you need to use ActiveSupport::OrderedHash.

Answer (score 8):

Hashes are fundamentally unsorted data structures; `Hash#sort` is, indeed, what you want. Either that, or sort a list of keys and then use that to enumerate when it's time to output the hash, instead of enumerating directly over the hash using its own methods.

Comment: Technically, Hashes are ordered in Ruby 1.9. But I think it's still generally better to treat them as if they weren't, since support for reordering and such does not exist.

Comment: Jim, can you give me an example?

Comment: "Technically, Hashes are ordered in Ruby 1.9"...this makes me very sad.  A hash is not supposed to have any implicit order!  Sure, I understand wanting ordering sometimes...but create a different name for that data structure!  Grr.