# Generate hash for value 1 to 31 with ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I generate hash something like this ?

```
{1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3}
```

from 1 to 31 with loop.

Comment: What use does it have? It looks useless to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For example:

```
(1..31).inject({}) { |h, k| h[k] = k; h}
```

If you want a hash that works for all numbers, you can do it this way:

```
>> h = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = k } #=> {}
>> h[221] #=> 221
```

Comment: I think the hash constructor is the nicest way to go.

Comment: Neat trick with the default value block. The inject method will create a bunch of throw-away hashes, though, fairly wasteful.

Comment: @Rob: I guess I should have explicitly mentioned that I prefer the second way. For just creating the hash to 31 I think nothing really beats `Hash[r.zip(r)]`.

Answer (score 6):

```
def generate_hash r
  Hash[r.zip r]
end

generate_hash (1..31)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
h = Hash.new()
for i in 1..31
    h[i] = i
end
```

Also, the question did not specify whether the order is important, but if order is important, you might want to consider a different sorting options, as describe here

[Sorting Hash of Hashes by value (and return the hash, not an array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983444/sorting-hash-of-hashes-by-value-and-return-the-hash-not-an-array)

Comment: `(1..31).each {|num| h[num] = num}` I would be willing to bet however your code is faster from a performance standpoint.

Answer (score 3):

Another one-liner:

```
Hash[(1..31).map {|i| [i,i]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(1..31).inject({}) { |hash, item| hash.merge(item => item) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this? Are you doing this because there's 31 days in a month?

Anyway:

```
hash = Hash.new() {|_, key| key if (1..31).include?(key) }
hash[1] # => 1
hash[31] # => 31
hash[32] # => nil
```

**Edit:** Now with code golfing from Michael Kohl!

Comment: Clever :-) I don't really like ternaries where one of the possible results is `nil`, so I'd probably just do `hash = Hash.new {|_, key| key if (1..31).include?(key) }`.

Answer (score 0):

My small contribution:

```
Hash[1.upto(31).zip 1.upto(31)]
```

or

```
Hash[(1.upto 31).zip(1.upto 31)]
```